# How to code an android application update from the Android Market

Tags: android

I am developing an android application with one basic function, to allow the user to click a button and download the full app from the android market (a virtual preload type app similar to the apps which come pre-loaded on the phone, which you have to actually install first to use) .

In my Activity class I create a Button and call the setOnClickListener...

```
marketButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String urlToMarket = "market://search?q=<package.name>";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(urlToMarket));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

i get an `ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle intent.` How do I code a handler for this intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Opens Android Market to install an App
 * 
 * @param context
 *            A Context to use
 * @param appId
 *            The appId, eg "de.bulling.smstalk"
 */
public static void installFromMarket(Context context, String appId) {
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+appId));
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Could not open Android Market.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great to hear! If that solved your problem, please mark the question as solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need market app to be installed to handle the uri.

Comment: thanks for this tip.. it gave me the idea to try the code on my actual phone instead of the AVD, the code seemed to work from my phone... but i've got a chicken before the egg problem where my app isn't on the marketplace yet, so i don't know for sure.

Comment: Good to know it has helped you. Please select the answer.. And for searching an application in market you should have its main package (app id) to be registered with market.